# How do I get the Huawei App Linking work with QR code scan?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Following documentation from [Huawei Developer site](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-applinking-introduction-0000001054143215), I created an app to intercept links from certain hostnames used as deep-links.

The app launches fine with the app link from an email shown as a URL. But when I tried to scan the QR code generated by [Huawei Developer site](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/service/josp/agc/index.html#/myProject) using the following steps: Settings-Huawei ID - Scan, the URL looks the same, select OK, the phone will end up displaying the page asking for download or open the web page as this is set as fall back step.

This problem happens only to HTTPS or HTTP schemes on HMS-only devices. Does the app-linking work with HTTP(S) for HMS-only devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use QR scanner built in the browser. Huawei ID QR scanner seems having a different handling of decoded information.

Answer (score 0):

The Huawe AppGallery Connect(AGC) App Linking can support Android and iOS system now, and it can run independently of the HMS. You can see more information at [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-applinking-introduction-0000001054143215).